# Группы доступа 1с по Организации не работают

Tags: 1с, права-доступа

УТ 11.5

Натыкал галочек в группу доступа "Продавец"

```
Базовые права БП
Базовые права БСП
Базовые права УТ
Вывод на принтер, в файл, в буфер обмена
Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после отгрузки по реализации
Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после перемещения
Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после приемки по возврату от клиента
Добавление и изменение внутренних потреблений товаров
Добавление и изменение возвратов товаров от клиентов
Добавление и изменение выданных доверенностей
Добавление и изменение выкупов возвратной тары клиентами
Добавление и изменение графиков работы
Добавление и изменение договоров контрагентов
Добавление и изменение документов корректировки задолженности (зачет оплаты)
Добавление и изменение документов по кассе
Добавление и изменение документов прочих доходов и расходов
Добавление и изменение задач проектов
Добавление и изменение заказов клиентов
Добавление и изменение заказов на внутреннее потребление
Добавление и изменение заказов на перемещение
Добавление и изменение заметок
Добавление и изменение заявлений о ввозе товаров
Добавление и изменение заявок на возврат товаров от клиента
Добавление и изменение кассовой смены
Добавление и изменение корректировок реализаций
Добавление и изменение листов кассовой книги
Добавление и изменение личных вариантов отчетов
Добавление и изменение личных шаблонов сообщений
Добавление и изменение напоминаний
Добавление и изменение настройки печати объектов по партнерам
Добавление и изменение операций по платежным картам
Добавление и изменение папок и файлов
Добавление и изменение претензий клиентов
Добавление и изменение расходных ордеров на товары
Добавление и изменение реализаций товаров услуг
Добавление и изменение сборок товаров
Добавление и изменение сертификатов ключей электронной подписи и шифрования
Добавление и изменение сертификатов номенклатуры
Добавление и изменение согласование продажи
Добавление и изменение счетов на оплату клиентам
Добавление и изменение счетов-фактур выданных
Добавление и изменение счетов-фактур комиссионеру
Добавление и изменение счетов-фактур полученных
Добавление и изменение транспортных накладных
Добавление и изменение транспортных средств
Добавление и изменение электронных подписей
Добавление изменение коммерческих предложений клиентам
Добавление изменение физических лиц
Запуск веб-клиента
Запуск толстого клиента
Запуск тонкого клиента
Зачет оплаты
Изменение дополнительных сведений
Изменение и выполнение задач
Изменение курса в документах продажи
Изменение складской информации по номенклатуре
Использование дополнительных отчетов и обработок УТ
Использование мобильного приложения "1С:Заказы"
Использование обработки "Журнал документов интеркампани"
Использование обработки "Журнал документов продажи"
Использование обработки текущие дела
Использование подключаемого оборудования
Использование помощника продаж
Использование рабочего места работника склада
Отклонение от условий продаж
Отчеты и обработки кладовщика
Отчеты и обработки менеджера по розничной торговле
Отчеты и обработки участников согласования условий продаж
Отчеты кассира
Отчеты менеджера по продажам
Отчеты раздела "Склад"
Печать документов отгрузки
Подсистема продажи
Получение платежной ссылки для ЮКаssa
Продавец
Просмотр валют
Просмотр отчета "Исполнение плана продаж"
Просмотр отчета движения документа
Просмотр отчета состояние выполнения документа
Просмотр отчета товары с истекающими сертификатами
Просмотр связанные документы
Раздел CRM и маркетинг: конкурентная разведка
Раздел закупки
Раздел казначейство денежные средства
Раздел казначейство эквайринг
Раздел маркетинг планирование
Раздел органайзер
Раздел продажи
Раздел продажи ведение заказов клиентов
Раздел продажи контроль расчетов с клиентами
Раздел продажи продажи и возвраты
Раздел продажи розничные продажи
Реализация сверх заказа
Редактирование реквизитов объектов
Редактирование, отправка по почте, сохранение в файл печатных форм
Сохранение настроек печати объектов по умолчанию
Удаленный доступ (Обмен сообщениями)
Чтение актов о расхождениях после перемещения
Чтение ассортимента
Чтение бонусных программ лояльности
Чтение видов карт лояльности
Чтение внутренних потреблений товаров
Чтение выданных доверенностей
Чтение выручки от продаж
Чтение графика платежей
Чтение графиков работы
Чтение документов корректировки задолженности
Чтение документов передачи товаров между организациями
Чтение документов прочих доходов и расходов
Чтение дополнительных отчетов и обработок
Чтение дополнительных сведений
Чтение заданий на перевозку
Чтение заданий торговым представителям
Чтение заказов на внутреннее потребление
Чтение заказов на перемещение
Чтение информации по номенклатуре
Чтение информации по партнерам
Чтение касс
Чтение кассовой книги
Чтение кассовых ордеров
Чтение корректировок обособленного учета запасов
Чтение курсов валют
Чтение назначений
Чтение новостей
Чтение номенклатуры партнеров
Чтение нормативно справочной информации
Чтение операций по платежной карте
Чтение операций с подарочными сертификатами
Чтение организаций и банковских счетов организаций
Чтение остатков денежных средств в кассе ККМ
Чтение остатков денежных средств к расходу
Чтение остатков доступных товаров
Чтение остатков заказов клиентов заявок на возврат
Чтение остатков переданной возвратной тары
Чтение остатков товаров к отгрузке
Чтение остатков товаров к поступлению
Чтение остатков товаров на складах
Чтение относительных курсов валют
Чтение отчетов комиссионеров
Чтение отчетов комитенту
Чтение отчетов о розничных продажах
Чтение перемещений товаров
Чтение пересчетов товаров
Чтение подключаемого оборудования offline
Чтение претензий клиентов
Чтение приобретений услуг прочих активов
Чтение проверок состояния системы
Чтение прочих доходов расходов
Чтение расчетов с клиентами
Чтение расчетов с поставщиками
Чтение реализаций товаров услуг
Чтение реализаций услуг и прочих активов
Чтение сборок товаров
Чтение соглашений с клиентами
Чтение соглашений с поставщиками
Чтение счетов-фактур выданных
Чтение счетов-фактур полученных
Чтение товаров к оформлению излишков недостач
Чтение товаров организаций
Чтение упаковочных листов
Чтение физических лиц
Чтение цен номенклатуры
Чтение цен номенклатуры с ограничением
Чтение чеков ККМ
Шифрование и расшифровка данных
```

Ограничение Организации все запрещенны, исключение в группе - не работает.

Но в этом профиле ограничение работает совместно с группой доступа партнеров

```
Базовые права Библиотеки интеграции с 1С:Документооборотом
Базовые права БП
Базовые права БСП
Базовые права БТС
Базовые права ГИСМ
Базовые права ЕГАИС
Базовые права Интернет-поддержки пользователей
Базовые права ИС МП
Базовые права по электронным документам
Базовые права УТ
Вывод на принтер, в файл, в буфер обмена
Выполнение обмена с контрагентами
Выполнение синхронизации данных
Добавление и изменение заданий
Добавление и изменение заданий торговым представителям
Добавление и изменение заказов клиентов
Добавление и изменение заметок
Добавление и изменение заявок на возврат товаров от клиента
Добавление и изменение маршрутов подписания
Добавление и изменение напоминаний
Добавление и изменение цен партнеров
Добавление и изменение электронных документов
Добавление изменение запросы коммерческих предложений от клиента
Добавление изменение номенклатуры контрагентов
Запуск веб-клиента
Запуск внешнего соединения
Запуск мобильного клиента
Запуск толстого клиента
Запуск тонкого клиента
Изменение и выполнение задач
Использование интеграции с 1С:Документооборотом
Использование мобильного приложения "1С:Заказы"
Использование обеспечение потребностей
Использование обработки "Журнал документов продажи"
Использование обработки текущие дела
Использование проверки количества товаров в документе
Использование уведомлений ЭДО
Использование электронной подписи в модели сервиса
Отклонение от условий продаж
Отчеты и обработки кладовщика
Отчеты и обработки торгового представителя
Передача данных (анонимный доступ)
Печать документов отгрузки
Подсистема продажи
Подсистема продажи базовая
Просмотр валют
Просмотр связанные документы
Раздел CRM и маркетинг: ценообразование
Раздел органайзер
Раздел продажи
Раздел продажи ведение заказов клиентов
Раздел продажи управление торговыми представителями
Расшифровка данных
Редактирование, отправка по почте, сохранение в файл печатных форм
Сохранение данных пользователя
Удаленный доступ (Обмен сообщениями)
Удаленный доступ (Передача данных)
Чтение 1С:Номенклатуры
Чтение актов о расхождениях после отгрузки
Чтение актов о расхождениях после приемки по возврату от клиента
Чтение ассортимента
Чтение бонусных программ лояльности
Чтение видов карт лояльности
Чтение возвратов товаров от клиентов
Чтение графика платежей
Чтение графиков работы
Чтение движений Номенклатура - Номенклатура
Чтение движений номенклатура контрагент
Чтение договоров контрагентов
Чтение дополнительных сведений
Чтение заказов клиентов заявок на возврат товаров от клиента
Чтение информации по номенклатуре
Чтение информации по партнерам
Чтение карт лояльности
Чтение корректировок реализаций
Чтение курсов валют
Чтение маршрутов подписания
Чтение назначений
Чтение настроек обмена данными с КПК
Чтение настроек обмена с контрагентами
Чтение настроек электронного взаимодействия
Чтение номенклатуры контрагентов
Чтение номенклатуры партнеров
Чтение нормативно справочной информации
Чтение организаций и банковских счетов организаций
Чтение остатков доступных товаров
Чтение остатков заказов клиентов заявок на возврат
Чтение остатков товаров к отгрузке
Чтение остатков товаров к поступлению
Чтение остатков товаров на складах
Чтение отборов размещений товаров
Чтение относительных курсов валют
Чтение планов остатков
Чтение претензий клиентов
Чтение расчетов с клиентами
Чтение реализаций товаров услуг
Чтение себестоимости товаров
Чтение соглашений с клиентами
Чтение состояния заказов клиента
Чтение счетов-фактур выданных
Чтение счетов-фактур полученных
Чтение товаров к оформлению излишков недостач
Чтение товаров организаций
Чтение упаковочных листов
Чтение цен номенклатуры
Чтение цен номенклатуры с ограничением
Чтение цен партнеров
Чтение шаблонов этикеток и ценников
Чтение штрихкодов упаковок товаров
Чтение электронных документов
Шифрование и расшифровка данных
```

Сейчас такие права (только различия) но всеравно не работает фильтр по организации.

```
                                                                                  > Базовые права Библиотеки интеграции с 1С:Документооборотом
                                                                                  > Базовые права БП
                                                                                  > Базовые права БТС
                                                                                  > Базовые права ГИСМ
                                                                                  > Базовые права ЕГАИС
                                                                                  > Базовые права Интернет-поддержки пользователей
                                                                                  > Базовые права ИС МП
                                                                                  > Базовые права по электронным документам
< Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после отгрузки по реализации
< Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после перемещения
< Добавление и изменение актов о расхождениях после приемки по возврату от клиента
< Добавление и изменение внесения выемки ДС по кассе ККМ
< Добавление и изменение внутренних потреблений товаров
< Добавление и изменение возвратов товаров от клиентов
< Добавление и изменение выкупов возвратной тары клиентами
< Добавление и изменение договоров контрагентов
< Добавление и изменение документов корректировки задолженности (зачет оплаты)
< Добавление и изменение документов по кассе
< Добавление и изменение документов прочих доходов и расходов

                                                                                  > Выполнение обмена с контрагентами
                                                                                  > Выполнение синхронизации данных
< Добавление и изменение задач проектов

                                                                                  > Добавление и изменение заданий торговым представителям
< Добавление и изменение заказов на внутреннее потребление
< Добавление и изменение заказов на перемещение
< Добавление и изменение заказов на сборку
< Добавление и изменение заказов поставщикам
< Добавление и изменение заявлений о ввозе товаров
< Добавление и изменение карт лояльности
< Добавление и изменение кассовой смены
< Добавление и изменение корректировок реализаций
< Добавление и изменение листов кассовой книги
< Добавление и изменение личных вариантов отчетов
< Добавление и изменение личных шаблонов сообщений

                                                                                  > Добавление и изменение маршрутов подписания
< Добавление и изменение настройки печати объектов по партнерам
< Добавление и изменение операций по платежным картам
< Добавление и изменение папок и файлов
< Добавление и изменение претензий клиентов
< Добавление и изменение расходных ордеров на товары
< Добавление и изменение реализаций возвратов подарочных сертификатов
< Добавление и изменение реализаций товаров услуг
< Добавление и изменение сборок товаров
< Добавление и изменение сертификатов номенклатуры
< Добавление и изменение согласование продажи
< Добавление и изменение счетов на оплату клиентам
< Добавление и изменение счетов-фактур выданных
< Добавление и изменение транспортных накладных
< Добавление и изменение чеков ККМ
< Добавление и изменение чеков ККМ коррекции
< Добавление изменение коммерческих предложений клиентам

                                                                                  > Добавление и изменение цен партнеров
                                                                                  > Добавление и изменение электронных документов
                                                                                  > Добавление изменение запросы коммерческих предложений от клиента
                                                                                  > Добавление изменение номенклатуры контрагентов
                                                                                  > Запуск внешнего соединения
< Зачет оплаты
< Изменение дополнительных сведений
< Изменение курса в документах продажи
< Изменение складской информации по номенклатуре
< Использование дополнительных отчетов и обработок УТ

                                                                                  > Использование интеграции с 1С:Документооборотом

< Использование обработки "Журнал документов продажи (накладные к оформлению)"

                                                                                  > Использование обеспечение потребностей
< Использование подключаемого оборудования
< Использование помощника продаж
< Использование рабочего места работника склада

                                                                                  > Использование проверки количества товаров в документе
                                                                                  > Использование уведомлений ЭДО
                                                                                  > Использование электронной подписи в модели сервиса
< Отчеты и обработки менеджера по розничной торговле
< Отчеты и обработки участников согласования условий продаж
< Отчеты кассира
< Отчеты кассира ККМ
< Отчеты менеджера по продажам
< Отчеты раздела "Склад"

                                                                                  > Отчеты и обработки торгового представителя
                                                                                  > Передача данных (анонимный доступ)
< Получение платежной ссылки для ЮКаssa
< Продавец

                                                                                  > Подсистема продажи базовая
< Просмотр отчета "Исполнение плана продаж"
< Просмотр отчета движения документа
< Просмотр отчета состояние выполнения документа
< Просмотр отчета товары с истекающими сертификатами
< Просмотр этапов оплаты клиентом
< Раздел CRM и маркетинг: ассортимент
< Раздел CRM и маркетинг: конкурентная разведка
< Раздел казначейство денежные средства
< Раздел казначейство эквайринг
< Раздел маркетинг планирование

                                                                                  > Раздел CRM и маркетинг: ценообразование
< Раздел продажи контроль расчетов с клиентами
< Раздел продажи продажи и возвраты
< Раздел продажи розничные продажи
< Реализация сверх заказа
< Редактирование реквизитов объектов

                                                                                  > Раздел продажи управление торговыми представителями
                                                                                  > Расшифровка данных
< Сохранение настроек печати объектов по умолчанию

                                                                                  > Сохранение данных пользователя
                                                                                  > Удаленный доступ (Обмен сообщениями)
                                                                                  > Удаленный доступ (Передача данных)
                                                                                  > Чтение 1С:Номенклатуры
< Чтение актов о расхождениях после перемещения

                                                                                  > Чтение актов о расхождениях после приемки по возврату от клиента
< Чтение вариантов отчетов
< Чтение внутренних потреблений товаров
< Чтение выручки от продаж

                                                                                  > Чтение возвратов товаров от клиентов
< Чтение движений Денежные средства - Доходы/Расходы
< Чтение движений Денежные средства - Контрагент
< Чтение движений денежных средств
< Чтение движений Доходы\Расходы - Прочие активы\пассивы
< Чтение движений Контрагент - Доходы/Расходы
< Чтение движений Контрагент - Контрагент
< Чтение движений Номенклатура - Доходы\Расходы
< Чтение документов корректировки задолженности
< Чтение документов прочих доходов и расходов
< Чтение дополнительных отчетов и обработок
< Чтение заданий на перевозку
< Чтение заданий торговым представителям
< Чтение заказов на внутреннее потребление
< Чтение заказов на перемещение

                                                                                  > Чтение заказов клиентов заявок на возврат товаров от клиента
< Чтение касс
< Чтение кассовой книги
< Чтение кассовых ордеров

                                                                                  > Чтение корректировок реализаций
                                                                                  > Чтение маршрутов подписания
                                                                                  > Чтение назначений
                                                                                  > Чтение настроек обмена данными с КПК
                                                                                  > Чтение настроек обмена с контрагентами
                                                                                  > Чтение настроек электронного взаимодействия
< Чтение обменов с ЮКаssа
< Чтение операций по платежной карте
< Чтение операций по Яндекс.Кассе
< Чтение операций с подарочными сертификатами
< Чтение остатков денежных средств в кассе ККМ
< Чтение остатков денежных средств к расходу

< Чтение остатков заказов поставщикам
< Чтение отгрука товаров ИС МП

                                                                                  > Чтение отборов размещений товаров
< Чтение отчетов комиссионеров
< Чтение отчетов комитенту
< Чтение отчетов о розничных возвратах
< Чтение отчетов о розничных продажах
< Чтение перемещений товаров
< Чтение пересчетов товаров

                                                                                  > Чтение планов остатков

< Чтение прочих доходов расходов
< Чтение расчетов с поставщиками
< Чтение реализаций услуг и прочих активов
< Чтение сборок товаров
< Чтение соглашений с поставщиками

                                                                                  > Чтение состояния заказов клиента
                                                                                  > Чтение товаров организаций
                                                                                  > Чтение цен номенклатуры

< Чтение чеков ККМ

                                                                                  > Чтение цен партнеров
                                                                                  > Чтение шаблонов этикеток и ценников
                                                                                  > Чтение штрихкодов упаковок товаров
                                                                                  > Чтение электронных документов
```

Comment: Ох, уж эти разграничения прав! Тёмная тема.